# How to extract multiple substring from a column through set operation in pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, set

> I created a Dataframe df, with these names. I tried to extract substrings from a column using set operation. But I'm **not able to extract more than a word(multiple strings)**. All I can extract is a single word. 
>   Please check my **Obtained output** and the **Expected output** and provide an efficient solution for this

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"Names":["This is Santhosh","This is Sneha Alphonse Shaji","This is Vikram Karthi"]})
df

Name_set={'Santhosh','Sneha Alphonse Shaji','Vikram Karthi'}
def sub(x):
    df_words= set(x.split(' '))
    extract_words=Name_set.intersection(df_words)
    return ' '.join(extract_words)

df['Extracted Names']= df.Names.apply(sub)
df
```

[Obtained Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnbea.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"Names":["This is Santhosh","This is Sneha Alphonse Shaji","This is Vikram Karthi"]})
df

Name_set=['Santhosh','Sneha Alphonse Shaji','Vikram Karthi']
def sub(x):
    ans =  [y for y in Name_set if y in x]
    return ' '.join(ans)


df['Extracted Names']= df.Names.apply(sub)
df 

               Names                Extracted Names
0   This is Santhosh                Santhosh
1   This is Sneha Alphonse Shaji    Sneha Alphonse Shaji
2   This is Vikram Karthi           Vikram Karthi
```